# RMySQL Syntax Error on "DROP INDEX" statement

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I can't seem to figure out what have went wrong here.

I am trying to run a sql query in R and I got the following error:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :    could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP INDEX `PRIMARY` ON temporary_table' at line 2
```

The following is my code:

```
library(RMySQL)

con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 user="XXX", password="XXX",
                 dbname="test", host="localhost")

query <- "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table LIKE test.helloworld;
         DROP INDEX `PRIMARY` ON temporary_table;"

rs <- dbSendQuery(con, query) #Where the error occurs
```

I have run the exact same query in mySQL and it is totally working.

Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Try running each query separately

Comment: show structure of helloword table.

Comment: Yup, running each query separately works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the query in 2 parts. first part create table and second part drop the index. for ex-

```
query <- "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table LIKE test.helloworld;"
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, query) #Where the error occurs

query <- "DROP INDEX `PRIMARY` ON temporary_table;"
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, query) #Where the error occurs
```

I have tested in in php. This have same problem in php. Its running fine.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "test");
$result = $mysqli->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temporary_table` LIKE t;");
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
$result = $mysqli->query(" DROP INDEX `PRIMARY` ON temporary_table;");
#$result = $mysqli->query("DROP table temporary_table;");
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
?>
root@smart:/var/www# php test.php
Errormessage: 
Errormessage:
```

When i run both the query in one then is say error as you said.

```
<?php
// mysqli
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "test");
$result = $mysqli->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temporary_table` LIKE t;DROP INDEX `PRIMARY` ON temporary_table;");
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
?>
root@smart:/var/www# php test.php
Errormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP INDEX `PRIMARY` ON temporary_table' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems due to you are trying to drop primary key even primary key column have a auto_increment property, so just modify column to remove auto_increment property then you can drop primary key as auto_increment needs a unique key.

You can use below syntax-

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table LIKE test.helloworld;
    alter table temporary_table modify column primary_key_column_with_all_properties_except_auto_increment, 
    DROP KEY `PRIMARY`;
```